# Java Data Synchronisation with database

Tags: java, database, synchronization

I have an application that permit the users to save data into a database. These date have constraints, for example :
Two data can't have the same value.
The idea is when you try to save data, the program will look into the database and see if there is a data with the same value, if there is, the program will show an exception, if not it will save the data. The problem is what if two threads save their data at the same time and those data have the same value, how can I prevent that from happening.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: What type of database is it? If you are using a standard SQL implementation, SQL should handle this for you (so long as your database constraints have been setup correctly)

Comment: Hello @Alfie  thank you for your answer, so i use a multiple types of database (MYSQL,POSTGRESQL,ORACLE), and the issue is when two threads have the same values execute the executeQuery (which is a  jdbc's method)  at the same time ..

Comment: The normal solution is to define constraints on your database tables (eg a primary key or a unique constraint), then the database management system takes care of this.

Comment: Hello Mark, yes i got you, but the problem here i'll change the db structure , so that's why im looking for a solution in the code, thank you anyway